# How can Node.js (v14) be forced to use more RAM?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tfjs-node, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to train a quite memory-hungry Tensorflow.js model, but I am running into some very strange Node.js behavior.

```
$ node --max-old-space-size=16384 --initial-old-space-size=16384 --max-heap-size=16384 --initial-heap-size=16384 index.js
2020-08-19 11:32:56.190067: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-08-19 11:32:56.213573: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3400000000 Hz
2020-08-19 11:32:56.216786: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55fce50 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-19 11:32:56.217643: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version


<--- Last few GCs --->

[19219:0x44d06a0]   162448 ms: Scavenge 4047.5 (4054.3) -> 4047.5 (4054.3) MB, 26.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.989, current mu = 0.989) allocation failure
[19219:0x44d06a0]   163150 ms: Scavenge 4430.0 (4436.8) -> 4430.0 (4436.8) MB, 36.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.989, current mu = 0.989) allocation failure
[19219:0x44d06a0]   164237 ms: Scavenge 5003.8 (5010.6) -> 5003.8 (5010.6) MB, 51.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.989, current mu = 0.989) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x9fd5f0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x94a45d node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb7099e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb70d17 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd1a905  [node]
 6: 0xcf3445  [node]
 7: 0xe7b96e  [node]
 8: 0xe7baba  [node]
 9: 0x10185b3 v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x13cc8f9  [node]
[1]    19219 abort (core dumped)  node --max-old-space-size=16384 --initial-old-space-size=16384   index.js
```

It seems I cannot force node to have more memory! Even though on my machine currently there is 32 GB installed, of which only 17GB is occupied, so if anything it should go up to occupying at least 15GB. And yet it usually dies after allocating 3-5GB.

Is this a bug in Node.js? Perhaps a regression from earlier versions? Do I have any options or perhaps I might have to re-compile my own Node binary? And if I do that, will that work?

EDIT: I run 64 bit node. `node -p "os.arch()"` says `x64`.

Comment: Ah, sorry that I forgot to specify, "of course" I run 64 bit. `node -p "os.arch()"` says `x64`

Comment: Would you mind to run [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Eomm/6fb82fd223704959985b3ab07320a30c) to define is it a node.js problem?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Sure. I've ran that and a slightly larger variant, and [these are the results](https://gist.github.com/Wizek/6dac1858dd601f96cd30095ffd6eeabd).